# How to get binding informations for a .Net assembly 

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, reference, bin

I have a dll in the bin folder of my project and I am not able to understand why it is there.

It looks like it is not required by the project, indeed if I remove it the application runs fine. 
Actually, when it is there it crash! :D

Every time I build with Visual Studio 2010 the dll is copied again.

The question is: is there a way/tool that can help me to understand who requires this dll in my app?
My application is an ASP.NET MVC 2 project.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the name of that DLL?

Comment: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.dl

Comment: The error is: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

It is right, because the dll is 32bit and my web app is 64.

Comment: You must have a reference from your project somewhere to the 32bit dll. When you delete it the 64bit dll is likely loaded from GAC or just the VS path.

Comment: That dll is not referenced directly in my project. I believe it is required by another reference - I need to understand which one is. There it comes my question, is there a way/tool that can help me to understand who requires this dll in my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step is to enable the diagnostic log for the build in Visual Studio:

```
Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run
```

then select

```
MSBUild project build output verbosity : Diagnostic
```

This will provide a full log into your output folder. So i could get this information:

```
C:\MyApplication\bin\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.dll
C:\MyApplication\bin\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.dll
    ResolvedFrom = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 SDK\VisualStudioIntegration\Common\Assemblies\v4.0
    CopyLocal = true
    FusionName = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    HintPath = \\Microsoft\WF4\Microsoft.VisualStudio.ActivityPack.Data.dll
    OriginalItemSpec = Microsoft.VisualStudio.ActivityPack.Data
    Version = 10.0.0.0
```

This tells me that the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Settings.dll is required by Microsoft.VisualStudio.ActivityPack.Data.dll

Another helpful tool is **fuslogvw.exe** (included in VS). It gives you full informations about an assembly origins. More informations about this tool [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).